# The correct implementation of the output of subcategories in the main category

Tags: magento2, category, blocks, sub-categories, viewmodel

i want to display subcategories in the root category, i found this way that works for me.

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml

```
<?php $category = $block->getCurrentCategory(); ?>
<?php $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php if(count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
    <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php foreach($category->getChildrenCategories() as $subcategory): ?>
                <?php $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcategory->getId()); ?>
                <li class="item product product-item">
                    <div class="product-item-info">
                        <?php if ($_imgUrl = $subcategory->getImageUrl()): ?>
                            <a href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                <span class="product-image-container">
                                    <?php $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />'; ?>
                                    <?php echo $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($subcategory, $_imgHtml, 'image'); ?>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="product details product-item-details">
                            <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                <a class="product-item-link" href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?= $subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
        <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this method alarms me with the fact that the `objectManager` is called to get the data, it is just as bad that this logic is used in the template.

Help implement this method through a block or View Model approach.

Still hope for help

Comment: Still hope for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ViewModel example**

Create module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xm
>
> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

Add to

> app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\SubCats</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create Class SubCats in your module

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;

class SubCats extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public $storeManager;

    public $viewAssetRepo;

    public  $coreRegistry;

    public $categoryFactory;

    public $catalogHelperOutput;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $viewAssetRepo,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output $catalogHelperOutput,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager        = $storeManager;
        $this->viewAssetRepo       = $viewAssetRepo;
        $this->coreRegistry        = $coreRegistry;
        $this->categoryFactory     = $categoryFactory;
        $this->catalogHelperOutput = $catalogHelperOutput;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {

        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if(!$category) return;

        $categoryId = $category->getId();

        $sortAttribute = $this->getSortAttribute();
        $model = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $categories = $model->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'url_key', 'url_path', 'image','description'])
            // ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $categoryId)
            ->addAttributeToSort($sortAttribute)
            ->addIsActiveFilter();

        return $categories;
    }

    public function getDescription($category)
    {
        $description = $category->getDescription();
        if ($description) {
            $categoryDescription = $this->catalogHelperOutput
                ->categoryAttribute($category, $description, 'description');
        } else {
            $categoryDescription = '';
        }
        return trim($categoryDescription);
    }

    public function getImage($category)
    {
        $placeholderImageUrl = $this->viewAssetRepo->getUrl(
            'Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg'
        );
        $image = $category->getImage();
        if ($image != null) {
            $url = $this->getImageUrl($image);
        } else {
            $url = $placeholderImageUrl;
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function getImageUrl($image)
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($image) {
            if (substr($image, 0, 1) === '/') {
                $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB
                    ) . ltrim($image, '/');
            } else {
                $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    ) . 'catalog/category/' . $image;
            }
        }
        return $url;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
    }
}
```

Your template in theme

> app/design/frontend/Theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var Vendor\Module\ViewModel\SubCats $viewmodel */
$viewmodel = $block->getViewModel();
?>

<?php if ($viewmodel->getCategories() && count($viewmodel->getCategories()) > 0): ?>
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
            <ol class="products list items product-items">
                <?php foreach($viewmodel->getCategories() as $subcategory): ?>
                    <li class="item product product-item">
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                            <?php if ($_imgUrl = $viewmodel->getImage($subcategory)): ?>
                                <a href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                <span class="product-image-container">
                                    <?php $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />'; ?>
                                    <?php echo $_imgHtml = $viewmodel->catalogHelperOutput->categoryAttribute($subcategory, $_imgHtml, 'image'); ?>
                                </span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                    <a class="product-item-link" href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?= $subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
        <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ( you can alter as per your need ):

in layout file use this block class ( Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category ):

```
<block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="category.left.navigation" template="Magento_Catalog::category/navigation_subcategory.phtml" />
```

in template file :

```
<div class="category-sldebar">
<?php

if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):
    $subcategories=$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getCategories($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId());
    /* count and check the category have any sub category */
    if($subcategories->count()>0){
        ?>
<h2>Categories</h2>
<ul class="list-category">
<?php
        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
            echo '<li class="parent-category"><a href="'.$this->getBaseUrl().$subcategory->getRequestPath().'"><strong class="title">' . $subcategory->getName() . '</strong></a>';
            if($subcategory->getChildrenCount() > 0)
            {
                $subcategories2=$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getCategories($subcategory->getId());
                echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
                foreach ($subcategories2 as $subsub) {
                    if ($subsub->getIsActive()) {
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getBaseUrl().$subsub->getRequestPath().'">' . $subsub->getName() . '</a></li>';
                    }
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }

    }else{
        // category does not have any sub category
    }
else:
    // category does not have any sub category
echo "</ul>";
endif;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: But, it doesn’t take logic out of the template into the block

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting or extending the block, you can use a view model instead.

https://www.yireo.com/blog/2017-08-12-viewmodels-in-magento-2

---

The following is just some rough code that should point you in the right direction.

You create an XML file `{{theme_dir}}/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` to inject the view model from

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\SubCats</argument>
     </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Now you can create your view model under `app/code/Vendor/Module/ViewModel` but with the code from your template abstracted into it.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;

class SubCats implements ArgumentInterface
{
    protected $_catRepo;    

    public function __construct (CategoryRepository $catRepo)
    {
        $this->_catRepo = $catRepo;
    }

    public function getCatById($id)
    {
        return $this->_catRepo->get($id);
    }

}
```

Then in your template file, you can now access these methods like so.

```
<?php 
$viewmodel = $block->getViewModel();
$category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

if(count($subcategories) > 0) {
  foreach($subcategories as $cat) {
    $cat = $viewmodel->getCatById($cat->getId());
    ... Do some more stuff and that
  }
}

?>


<?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()) :?>
    <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```